# Android new View() click dynamically

Tags: android, view

```
if(layout == null) {
       layout = new RelativeLayout(getActivity());
       RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new 
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
        ViewGroup parentView = (ViewGroup) getView().getRootView();
        parentView.addView(layout, params);
       }

            FlexNativeAd unit = new FlexNativeAd();
            unit.adId = adId;
            unit.x = unit.y = 0;
            unit.w = unit.h = 4;

            unit.tracking = new View(getActivity());
            layout.addView(unit.tracking, new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(unit.w, unit.h));
```

i want to click dynamically on view layout 
like in button we use doClick();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `layout.performClick();`